# How to simulate the @PreAutorize tag in a integration test?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following method in Spring MVC and using Spring Security:

```
@PreAuthorize("#phoneNumber == authentication.name")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{phoneNumber}/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView startUpgrading(@PathVariable("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,
       ....
}
```

I manage to simulate authentication something like this:

```
public Authentication tryToAuthenticate(String accountName, String password) {
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(accountName, password);
    return authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
}
```

But I dont know how to set up the authorization with @PreAutorize.

How can I set up my test context correctly such that I dont get access denied ?

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:205)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotations ( @PreAuthorize, @PostAuthorize, @PreFilter, @PostFilter ) which support expression attributes to allow pre & post-invocation authorization checks are enabled through the global-method-authority namespace element.

You need to add following code in your application-servlet.xml or security xml file.

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" >
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"   class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>
```

***Check*** [spring-testcontext-framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403818/how-to-junit-tests-a-preauthorize-annotation-and-its-spring-el-specified-by-a-s) answering question very similar to yours.

Comment: Sorry late response, this worked liked charm ! 50 bounty points to you. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @ThomasVervik ... I am glad that my answer helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to declare a mock version of the bean that does the Authentication. You might need a test context.xml to declare it.

Comment: I already have a text context xml, thats no problem. Any idea which bean is responsible for Autorization ?

Comment: Do you not specify it in your Spring security config?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087548/can-spring-security-use-preauthorize-on-spring-controllers-methods) old post and the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html) 16.3 Method Security Expressions for xml configuration.

I think you need to declare on your xml:

Also your method to authenticate token could be a *hasPermisions()*. Check [16.3.2 Built-In Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html)