# Spring Test & Security: How to mock authentication?

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller, testing, junit

I was trying to figure out how to unit test if my the URLs of my controllers are properly secured. Just in case someone changes things around and accidentally removes security settings.

My controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/resource/test") 
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public @ResonseBody String test() {
    return "test";
}
```

I set up a WebTestEnvironment like so:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({ 
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/security.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml" })
public class WebappTestEnvironment2 {

    @Resource
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("databaseUserService")
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    protected UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getPrincipal(String username) {

        UserDetails user = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = 
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user, 
                        user.getPassword(), 
                        user.getAuthorities());

        return authentication;
    }

    @Before
    public void setupMockMvc() throws NamingException {

        // setup mock MVC
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }
}
```

In my actual test I tried to do something like this:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;

import eu.ubicon.webapp.test.WebappTestEnvironment;

public class CopyOfClaimTest extends WebappTestEnvironment {

    @Test
    public void signedIn() throws Exception {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = 
                this.getPrincipal("test1");

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(principal);        

        super.mockMvc
            .perform(
                    get("/api/v1/resource/test")
//                    .principal(principal)
                    .session(session))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I picked this up here:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-test-mvc-junit-testing here:
- http://techdive.in/solutions/how-mock-securitycontextholder-perfrom-junit-tests-spring-controller or here:
- [[How to JUnit tests a @PreAuthorize annotation and its spring EL specified by a spring MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403818/how-to-junit-tests-a-preauthorize-annotation-and-its-spring-el-specified-by-a-s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403818/how-to-junit-tests-a-preauthorize-annotation-and-its-spring-el-specified-by-a-s)

Yet if one looks closely this only helps when not sending actual requests to URLs, but only when testing services on a function level. In my case an "access denied" exception was thrown:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        ...
```

The following two log messages are noteworthy basically saying that no user was authenticated indicating that setting the `Principal` did not work, or that it was overwritten.

```
14:20:34.454 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.List test.TestController.test(); target is of class [test.TestController]; Attributes: [ROLE_USER]
14:20:34.454 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

Comment: Your company name, eu.ubicon, is displayed in your import. Isn't that a security risk?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I can't see why though. It's open source software anyway. If you are interested, see https://bitbucket.org/ubicon/ubicon (or https://bitbucket.org/dmir_wue/everyaware for the latest fork). Let me know if I miss something.

Comment: Check this solution (the answer is for spring 4): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308341/how-to-login-a-user-with-spring-3-2-new-mvc-testing/47069613#47069613

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It turned out that the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, which is part of the Spring Security filter chain, always resets my `SecurityContext`, which I set calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(principal)` (or by using the `.principal(principal)` method). This filter sets the `SecurityContext` in the `SecurityContextHolder` with a `SecurityContext` from a `SecurityContextRepository` **OVERWRITING** the one I set earlier. The repository is a `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` by default. The `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` inspects the given `HttpRequest` and tries to access the corresponding `HttpSession`. If it exists, it will try to read the `SecurityContext` from the `HttpSession`. If this fails, the repository generates an empty `SecurityContext`.

Thus, my solution is to pass a `HttpSession` along with the request, which holds the `SecurityContext`:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;

import eu.ubicon.webapp.test.WebappTestEnvironment;

public class Test extends WebappTestEnvironment {

    public static class MockSecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1386535243513362694L;

        private Authentication authentication;

        public MockSecurityContext(Authentication authentication) {
            this.authentication = authentication;
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication getAuthentication() {
            return this.authentication;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
            this.authentication = authentication;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void signedIn() throws Exception {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = 
                this.getPrincipal("test1");

        MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
        session.setAttribute(
                HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, 
                new MockSecurityContext(principal));


        super.mockMvc
            .perform(
                    get("/api/v1/resource/test")
                    .session(session))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: We have not yet added official support for Spring Security. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2015 An outline for what it will look like is specified in https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/context/SpringSecurityTests.java

Comment: I don't think creating an Authentication object and adding a session with the corresponding attribute is that bad. Do you think this is a valid "work around"? Direct support on the other hand would be great of course. Looks pretty neat. Thanks for the link!

Comment: great solution. worked for me! just a minor issue with the naming of the protected method `getPrincipal()` which to my opinion is a bit misleading. ideally it should have been named `getAuthentication()`. likewise, in your `signedIn()` test, the local variable should be named `auth` or `authentication` instead of `principal`

Comment: What is "getPrincipal("test1") ¿?? Could you expline where is it that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2992476 It probably returns an object of type UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Alternatively, you create GrantedAuthority and construct this object.

Comment: If you have an own UserDetailsService, wouldn't be more convenient to mock out it or its internal state (e.g. the repository behind that service impl)? I didn't have to write anything, just mocking out an existing user retrieval from the repo (plus noop password encoder settings all around the integration test env).

Answer (score 188):

Seaching for answer I couldn't find any to be easy and flexible at the same time, then I found the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc) and I realized there are near to perfect solutions. AOP solutions often are the greatest ones for testing, and Spring provides it with `@WithMockUser`, `@WithUserDetails` and `@WithSecurityContext`, in this artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In most cases, `@WithUserDetails` gathers the flexibility and power I need.

## How @WithUserDetails works?

Basically you just need to create a custom `UserDetailsService` with all the possible users profiles you want to test. E.g

```
@TestConfiguration
public class SpringSecurityWebAuxTestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        User basicUser = new UserImpl("Basic User", "user@company.com", "password");
        UserActive basicActiveUser = new UserActive(basicUser, Arrays.asList(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERM_FOO_READ")
        ));

        User managerUser = new UserImpl("Manager User", "manager@company.com", "password");
        UserActive managerActiveUser = new UserActive(managerUser, Arrays.asList(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_MANAGER"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERM_FOO_READ"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERM_FOO_WRITE"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERM_FOO_MANAGE")
        ));

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(Arrays.asList(
                basicActiveUser, managerActiveUser
        ));
    }
}
```

Now we have our users ready, so imagine we want to test the access control to this controller function:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @Secured("ROLE_MANAGER")
    @GetMapping("/salute")
    public String saluteYourManager(@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser)
    {
        return String.format("Hi %s. Foo salutes you!", activeUser.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Here we have a *get mapped function* to the route **/foo/salute** and we are testing a role based security with the `@Secured` annotation, although you can test `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` as well.
Let's create two tests, one to check if a valid user can see this salute response and the other to check if it's actually forbidden.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = SpringSecurityWebAuxTestConfig.class
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class WebApplicationSecurityTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("manager@company.com")
    public void givenManagerUser_whenGetFooSalute_thenOk() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foo/salute")
                .accept(MediaType.ALL))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("manager@company.com")));
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("user@company.com")
    public void givenBasicUser_whenGetFooSalute_thenForbidden() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foo/salute")
                .accept(MediaType.ALL))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
}
```

As you see we imported `SpringSecurityWebAuxTestConfig` to provide our users for testing. Each one used on its corresponding test case just by using a straightforward annotation, reducing code and complexity.

## Better use @WithMockUser for simpler Role Based Security

As you see `@WithUserDetails` has all the flexibility you need for most of your applications. It allows you to use custom users with any GrantedAuthority, like roles or permissions. But if you are just working with roles, testing can be even easier and you could avoid constructing a custom `UserDetailsService`. In such cases, specify a simple combination of user, password and roles with [@WithMockUser](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withmockuser).

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@WithSecurityContext(
    factory = WithMockUserSecurityContextFactory.class
)
public @interface WithMockUser {
    String value() default "user";

    String username() default "";

    String[] roles() default {"USER"};

    String password() default "password";
}
```

The annotation defines default values for a very basic user. As in our case the route we are testing just requires that the authenticated user be a manager, we can quit using `SpringSecurityWebAuxTestConfig` and do this.

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = "MANAGER")
public void givenManagerUser_whenGetFooSalute_thenOk() throws Exception
{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foo/salute")
            .accept(MediaType.ALL))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("user")));
}
```

Notice that now instead of the user **manager@company.com** we are getting the default provided by `@WithMockUser`: **user**; yet it won't matter because what we really care about is his role: `ROLE_MANAGER`.

## Conclusions

As you see with annotations like `@WithUserDetails` and `@WithMockUser` we can *switch between different authenticated users scenarios* without building classes alienated from our architecture just for making simple tests. Its also recommended you to see how [@WithSecurityContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withsecuritycontext) works for even more flexibility.

Comment: How to mock *multiple users*? For instance, the first request is sent by `tom`, while the second is by `jerry`?

Comment: You can create a function where your test is with tom and create another test with the same logic and test it with Jerry. There will be a particular outcome for each test so there will be different assertions and if a test fails it will tell you by its name which user/role did not work. Remember that in a request the user can be only one, so to specify multiple users in a request does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry I mean such example scenario: We test that, tom creates a secret article, then jerry tries to read that, and jerry should not see it (since it is secret). So in this case, it is *one* unit test...

Comment: It looks pretty much like the `BasicUser` and `Manager User` scenario given in the answer. The key concept is that instead of caring about the users we actually care about their roles, but each of those tests, located in the same unit test, actually represent different queries. done by different users (with different roles) to the same endpoint.

Answer (score 104):

Since Spring 4.0+, the best solution is to annotate the test method with @WithMockUser

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user1", password = "pwd", roles = "USER")
public void mytest1() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/someApi"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Remember to add the following dependency to your project

```
'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:4.2.3.RELEASE'
```

Comment: Good answer. Moreover - you do not need to use mockMvc, but in case if you are using e.g. PagingAndSortingRepository from springframework.data - you can just call methods from the repository directly (which are annotated with EL @PreAuthorize(......))

Comment: Thanks, it gets better with @WithMockUser(roles = "YOUR_ROLE")

Comment: How to add orgId as well

Comment: just a small reminder that you don't have to explicitly add the version to your spring dependencies

Answer (score 32):

Add in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and use `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors` for authorization request. 
See the sample usage at https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-test-blog
(https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2592).

Update:

4.0.0.RC2 works for spring-security 3.x. 
For spring-security 4 spring-security-test become part of spring-security (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test, version is the same).

Setting Up is changed: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc

```
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())  
            .build();
}
```

Sample for basic-authentication: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#testing-http-basic-authentication.

Comment: This also fixed my issue with getting a 404 when trying to login via a login security filter. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, while testing as mentioned by GKislin. I am getting following error "Authentication failed UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation"  . Any suggestion please.         
final AuthenticationRequest auth = new AuthenticationRequest();
  auth.setUsername(userId);
  auth.setPassword(password);         mockMvc.perform(post("/api/auth/").content(json(auth)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example for those who want to Test Spring MockMvc Security Config using Base64 basic authentication.

```
String basicDigestHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(("<username>:<password>").getBytes()));
this.mockMvc.perform(get("</get/url>").header("Authorization", basicDigestHeaderValue).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Maven Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

```java
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder defaultRequestBuilder = get("/dummy-path");
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
            .defaultRequest(defaultRequestBuilder)
            .alwaysDo(result -> setSessionBackOnRequestBuilder(defaultRequestBuilder, result.getRequest()))
            .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
            .build();
}

private MockHttpServletRequest setSessionBackOnRequestBuilder(final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder,
                                                             final MockHttpServletRequest request) {
    requestBuilder.session((MockHttpSession) request.getSession());
    return request;
}
```

After perform `formLogin` from spring security test each of your requests will be automatically called as logged in user.

**Long answer:**

Check this solution (the answer is for spring 4): [How to login a user with spring 3.2 new mvc testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308341/how-to-login-a-user-with-spring-3-2-new-mvc-testing/47069613#47069613)

Answer (score 2):

Options to avoid using SecurityContextHolder in tests:

- **Option 1**: use mocks - I mean mock `SecurityContextHolder` using some mock library - *EasyMock* for example
- **Option 2**: wrap call `SecurityContextHolder.get...` in your code in some service - for example in `SecurityServiceImpl` with method `getCurrentPrincipal` that implements `SecurityService` interface and then in your tests you can simply create mock implementation of this interface that returns the desired principal without access to `SecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: Mh, maybe I don't get the whole picture. My problem was that the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter replaces the SecurityContext using a SecurityContext from a HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository, which in turn reads the SecurityContext from the corresponding HttpSession. Thus the solution using the session. Regarding the call to the SecurityContextHolder: I edited my answer so that I am not using a call to the SecurityContextHolder anymore. But also without introducing any wrapping or extra mocking libraries. Do you think, this is a better solution?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand exactly what you were looking for and I cannot provide better answer than the solution you came up with and  - it seems to be a good option.

Comment: All right, thanks. I will accept my proposal as a solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

When using `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(...)` than `springSecurityFilterChain` (more specifically `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`) will take over and will remove the `SecurityContext` prepared by `@WithMockUser` (pretty silly); this happens because `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` tries to "restore" the `SecurityContext` from the `HttpSession` where finds none. Well, use this simple `AutoStoreSecurityContextHttpFilter` defined below which will take care of putting `@WithMockUser`'s preppared `SecurityContext` into the `HttpSession` such that later `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will be able to find it.

```java
@ContextConfiguration(...) // the issue doesn't occur when using @SpringBootTest
public class SomeTest {
    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(WebApplicationContext wac) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .addFilters(new AutoStoreSecurityContextHttpFilter(), springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    @WithMockUser
    @Test
    void allowAccessToAuthenticated() {
        ...
    }
}

// don't use this Filter in production because it's only intended for tests, to solve the 
// @WithMockUser & springSecurityFilterChain (more specifically SecurityContextPersistenceFilter) "misunderstandings"
public class AutoStoreSecurityContextHttpFilter extends HttpFilter {
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        req.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Late answer though. But This has worked for me , and could be useful.

While Using Spring Security ans mockMvc, all you need to is use @WithMockUser annotation like others are mentioned.

Spring security also provides another annotation called **`@WithAnonymousUser`** for testing unauthenticated requests. However you should be careful here. You would be expecting 401, but I got 403 Forbidden Error by default. In actual scenarios, when you are running actual service, It is redirected and you end up getting the correct 401 response code.Use this annotation for anonymous requests.

You may also think of ommitting the annotaions and simply keep it unauthorized. But this usually raises the correct exceptions(like AuthenticationException), but you will get correct status code if it is handled correctly(If you are using custom handler). I used to get 500 for this. So look for the exceptions raised in the debugger, and check if it is handled rightly and returns the correct status code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `TestUserDetailsImpl` on your test package:

```
@Service
@Primary
@Profile("test")
public class TestUserDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    public static final String API_USER = "apiuser@example.com";

    private User getAdminUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(API_USER);

        SimpleGrantedAuthority role = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_API_USER");
        user.setAuthorities(Collections.singletonList(role));

        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) 
                                         throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (Objects.equals(username, ADMIN_USERNAME))
            return getAdminUser();
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
}
```

Rest endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/invoice")
@Secured("ROLE_API_USER")
public Page<InvoiceDTO> getInvoices(){
   ...
}
```

Test endpoint:

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails("apiuser@example.com")
public void testApi() throws Exception {
     ...
}
```