# Mock SpringContextHolder using MockMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I am writing unit test cases for Controller  layer. I have a call where i am getting user from Spring SecurityContextHolder. When i run my test case i get Null pointer exception because I don't know how to mock Spring security context.

Below is my code, any suggestion how to do it?

Controller Methhod:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveSettings(@RequestBody EmailSettingDTO emailSetting) {
    User user = ((CurrentUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser();
    settings.saveUserEmailSetting(user, emailSetting);

}
```

My Test case :

```
@Test  public void testSaveSettings() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(post(BASE_URL).content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(emailDto))
  .contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

}

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203485/spring-test-security-how-to-mock-authentication

Answer (score 0):

There is a Spring Security Test library for this purpose.

You can use `@WithMockUser` to achieve this. See the [post](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@WithUserDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/test/context/support/WithUserDetails.html)

> this annotation can be added to a test method to emulate running with a UserDetails returned from the UserDetailsService.

By using this, you create a context to run a test in, for example:

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails("admin")
public void testAdmin() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(...);
}
```

This will execute `testAdmin()` with the `SecurityContext` of admin.

But please note, in order to use this; there must be a `User` persisted with the name `admin`, otherwise you will get result exceptions.