# What is the equivalent of MockHttpServletRequestBuilder for websockets tests in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

What is the equivalent of MockHttpServletRequestBuilder for websockets. i.e. In a situation where I want to test Websockets., I would like to test a long running websocket application and avoid the situation where SecurityContextPersistenceFilter is overriding the SecurityContex after the first http get call that is supposed to do the upgrade. For plain rest http apps this was done so far by leveraging the SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.
example here [using the SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-test-blog/blob/master/src/test/java/sample/mockmvc/MockMvcCreateMessageTest.java)

But what to do when I want to test a long running websocket application. i.e. I want ot create something like  MockHttpServletRequestBuilder for websockets. Does spring have something like that already? Or is there a way to use MockHttpServletRequestBuilder for that purpose? I.e. the target is to create the websocket endpoint and avoid the situation where the SecurityContex is beeing cleared after the upgrade.

I have found some alternatives such as passing the session as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203485/spring-test-security-how-to-mock-authentication/15203488) but this is not really an alternative  for me as then the code that is using method level security does not work since the SecurityContex is being altered.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this can be done by providing a test sock config. Ex

```
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    static class TestWebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Autowired
        Environment env;

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS();
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
//          registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
            registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");
            registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        }
    }
```

The full class can be found here: 
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/context/ContextPortfolioControllerTests.java

Here are also some additional examples provided by spring the demonstrate 3 different approaches to testing web sockets:
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web