# Spring Security and MockMvc - Need to mock authentication or principal

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, mockmvc

I'm using Spring Security, and facing issue writing unit test case (using MockMvc) for a controller.

I have a method in my controller that goes something like this:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser){
    String userEmail = activeUser.getEmail();
    return userService.getUser(userEmail);
}
```

I get a 500 error with this.

Another variation for the controller I've tried is, and this is working on Postman/Curl :

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(OAuth2Authentication authentication){
    String userEmail = (String) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return userService.getUser(userEmail);
}
```

My service looks like :

```
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(String email) {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
            .map(record -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(record))
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

In my unit test case for this controller method, I have:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "1", password = "pwd", roles = "USER")
public void controller_should_get_user() throws Exception {
    when(userService.getUser("1")).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(userMock, HttpStatus.OK));
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/user/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.timecloud.user.controller.UserControllerTest.controller_should_get_user(UserControllerTest.java:60)
```

How should I go about passing or mocking a user with the current authentication? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`@WithMockUser` creates a `UsernameAuthenticationToken`, not an `OAuth2Authentication`.

At least three solutions here:

1. Inject an `OAuth2Authentication` mock or instance in the security context
2. change your method to `public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(Authentication authentication)`, then using `authentication.getName()` inside
3. use some existing tooling to apply solution `1.` for you, like in this [libs I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)

Sample usage with solution 1

```java
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final var storedRequest = mock(OAuth2Request);

    final var principal = mock(Principal.class);
    when(principal.getName()).thenReturn("user");

    final var userAuthentication = mock(Authentication.class);
    when(userAuthentication.getAuthorities()).thenReturn(Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    when(userAuthentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);

    final var oauth2Authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(storedRequest, authentication);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(oauth2Authentication);

    // use MockMvc to test a @Controller or unit-test any other secured @Component as usual
}
```

Sample usage with solution 3

```java
@Test
@WithMockAuthentication(authType = OAuth2Authentication.class, name = "user", authorities = "ROLE_USER")
public void test() throws Exception {
    // use MockMvc to test a @Controller or unit-test any other secured @Component as usual
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointerException` is coming because your test is unable to find anything for `OAuth2Authentication` Object. There are two things you can do your test case:

1. Try Mocking `OAuth2Authentication` in some setUp method.

OR

2. If you are using Spring 4.0+, the best solution is to annotate the test method with **@[WithMockUser](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-security-junit-test-with-withmockuser-and-withuserdetails-annotation-example-using-webappconfiguration)**

   `@Test
   @WithMockUser(username = "user1", password = "pwd", roles = "USER")
   public void mytest1() throws Exception {
        //Your test scenario
       }`

Comment: Updated my answer, with the use of @WithMockUser and AuthenticationPrincipal (instead of OAuth2Authentication). I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: can your share code for your user-service. may be you need to change your mocking for user service to :- `when(userService.getUser("1")).thenReturn(userMock);`

Comment: updated. But the whole point of mocking the service was to not care about the underlying implementation, isn't it?

Comment: correct but with mockmvc you are doing integration testing. check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203485/spring-test-security-how-to-mock-authentication for ref.

Comment: 1.) `@WithMockUser` creates a `UsernameAuthenticationToken`, not an `OAuth2Authentication` and 2.) one can make unit (not integration) testing with mockmvc if mocking / stubing all dependencies (with `@MockBean` for instance)