# How to mock authentication and authorization with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring-boot REST API application. The REST endpoints are protected by spring-security.

This is the configuration of spring-security:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomForbiddenErrorHandler())
            .and()

            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() // HTTP 403 if the request is not authenticated
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}
```

It works fine. If I make a rest call without having an auth-token on the HTTP header I get back the proper HTTP error code.

Can I force spring somehow to add a self auth-token if it is not presented in order so I can make REST calls without having my own access management system? It will be installed later.

I am not asking how to write JUnit test. What I am asking is how to generate a mock auth-token on the fly and add it to the request if it does not exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Test & Security: How to mock authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203485/spring-test-security-how-to-mock-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the existing authentication filter, or create a new custom filter, to check if a request contains a bearer token or not. Based on the result, you can either process the request as it is, or augment the request with your custom authentication object.

Check out [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.html), this extracts an OAuth2 token from the incoming request and uses it to populate the Spring Security context. You can either override its behavior or create a new filter that populates the security context with your mock authentication object.

Here is a sample code to get you started:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    boolean debug = logger.isDebugEnabled();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;

    try {
        Authentication authentication = this.tokenExtractor.extract(request);
        if (Objects.isNull(authentication)) {
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password");

            authenticationToken.setDetails(Collections.singletonMap("user_uuid", userUuid.toString()));

            final OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(null, authenticationToken);

            // You can either ask your authenticatoin manager to authenticate these credentials or directly publish auth success event with your mock auth object.

            this.eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(oAuth2Authentication);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(oAuth2Authentication);

        } else {
            request.setAttribute(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE, authentication.getPrincipal());
            if (authentication instanceof AbstractAuthenticationToken) {
                AbstractAuthenticationToken needsDetails = (AbstractAuthenticationToken)authentication;
                needsDetails.setDetails(this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
            }

            Authentication authResult = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            if (debug) {
                logger.debug("Authentication success: " + authResult);
            }

            this.eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(authResult);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        }
```